# Is it possible to hide or remove "File" "Edit" etc menus in a google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to hide or remove "File" "Edit" etc menus in a google spreadsheet and only the owner could see them? It works with script created menus but not with the default ones. Is there a workaround to prevent other editors from editing my script? Thanks

Comment: Give them View access only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide your code:
You could create stand alone scripts which contain all the logic and "secret sauce".

then from the speadsheet script just call these scripts as web services passing the necesary parameters.

As for hidding the menu items, you cannot. Only option would be to embed the sheet within a Google Site.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Put it on preview mode by url parameter. For example,

From:

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/abc_xyz/edit#
```

To:

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/abc_xyz/preview
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a partial solution to hide the code. Create an independant script and use the address of your spreadsheet to work on it:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=01234567890"); 
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

You can program the execution of the script( every 2 hours...etc) but you don't have the button in the spreadsheet.