# Disable google sheets menu default buttons

Tags: google-app-engine, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is it possible to disable the menu buttons on google sheets using the app script. I notice as the sheets load the buttons get disabled briefly which would indicate there is possibly some way of doing this.

Thanks for any advice in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based from this [blog](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/VXjZXqYfCu4), you can use `&rm=minimal` to hide the controls in a spreadsheet.

> In summary:
>
> - **&ui=2** - (required for rm=demo) renders the spreadsheet in the 'new' version interface (note &ui=1 renders the 'old' version
>     interface).
> - **&chrome=false** - renders the spreadsheet in full screen mode, i.e. without menu, controls (button bar) or formula bar
> - **&rm=demo** - renders the spreadsheet without the sheet menu, i.e. only one sheet (by default the first of a spreadsheet) is rendered
> - **#gid=n** - specifies which sheet to render; to set the default sheet to show or in combination with &rm=demo to render one single,
>     specific, sheet.

Check these related threads:

- [How to share google spreadsheet without menu bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27751830/how-to-share-google-spreadsheet-without-menu-bar)
- [Is it possible to hide or remove "File" "Edit" etc menus in a google spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16241147/is-it-possible-to-hide-or-remove-file-edit-etc-menus-in-a-google-spreadsheet)

Hope this helps!