# Removal of default Google sheet Menus

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using the Google sheet in an editable and embedded form in one of the product.

Need to disable default Menus as highlighted below.[image]

Is there a way to achieve this?

I could only find the option to `add` custom menu items. Couldn't find anything to remove default menu items.

Comment: You can check the solution in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38426693/disable-google-sheets-menu-default-buttons). I think this will help you from your problem.